# How to get Google Sheets to recognize I'm entering time in MM:SS?

Tags: google-sheets, time, formatting, duration

I am trying to record the time it takes for a number of things to occur, and can't seem to get Google Sheets to understand my input. I want to be able to type something like "26:30" into a cell, and have the spreadsheet understand that this means 26 minutes and 30 seconds, and then be able to use that number in formulas, e.g. to return the shortest of a series of times, or the difference between two times.

Also, the vast majority of the numbers I type in will be under an hour, so I don't want to have to type in something like "0:26:30" every time, just for it to understand that I mean 26 minutes, not 26 hours. However for the rare occasions where something is longer than an hour, I want to be able to be able to type something like "1:10:23" and not "70:23".

If possible, I would rather achieve this through directly formatting the cell I type the time into, rather than enter it in one format and have it converted in a separate cell via a formula.

Is there a way to do this that meets all of these goals?

Answer (score 2):

google sheets is not designed in such a way. if you want to type in `26:30` then the best course of action is as follows:

convert cells to `Plain Text`, type in your duration, and account for your rules within formulae. to convert a text string into a value for the sake of calculation you can use the following principle

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A, ":\d+:"), A1:A*1, ("0:"&A1:A)*1)))
```

[image]

few examples:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(AVERAGE(IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A2, ":\d+:"), 
 A1:A2*1, ("0:"&A1:A2)*1)), "[m]:ss"))
```

[image]

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SUM(IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A2, ":\d+:"), 
 A1:A2*1, ("0:"&A1:A2)*1)), "[h]:mm:ss"))
```

[image]

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2, ":\d+:"), A2*1, ("0:"&A2)*1)-
                   IF(REGEXMATCH(A1, ":\d+:"), A1*1, ("0:"&A1)*1), "[m]:ss"))
```

[image]

Comment: That formula is giving me some weird results. Times from 23:59 and down get formatted in the second column as 23:59:00, while only times higher than that seem to work.

Comment: I made a new sheet identical to your first example, but I put different numbers into cell A1. When they're above 24:00 everything works. Below that, and the first number gets interpreted as hours.

Comment: @Ulysses answer updated. try now

Comment: Can you explain what your formula is doing? I don't recognise those formulas, and I'm not sure how to interpret or adapt that code.

Comment: In the meantime I have manage to get this to work for the scenarios I've tested, but I don't know enough about it to know if it will work with all possible user inputs, including errors: ````=ARRAYFORMULA(time(left(A1:A3,if(len(A1:A3)<6,"",len(A1:A3)-6)),right(left(A1:A3,len(A1:A3)-3),2),right(A1:A3,2)))````

Comment: @Ulysses test possible scenarios or include your examples. you can serach about the functions in [google sheet help](https://support.google.com/docs#topic=1382883)

Comment: @Ulysses your final objective remains unknown same as your sheet structure so all we can provide you are examples that you may never need but you can learn from them tho. as mentioned if you format A column as plain text and input your times h:mm:ss or just mm:ss the formula will do following: IF REGEXMATCH will detect that A column contains pattern colon-number-colon :\d+: it means that input is in h:mm:ss format so it gets multiplied by 1 to convert string into value that can be further calculated. if inputed time dos not contain such patter it means you entered time in mm:ss format

Comment: so simple 0: is added infront of it to represent the 0 hour so the sheet would recognize it as time value after the multiplication. then you do your thing - whatever it is, MAX, MIN, AVERAGE,SUM.... and you will end up with a value. with that you have two options: format it as time or custom time via internal formatting. or your second option: use TEXT to output the value exactly as you want it to look like

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time there doesn't seem to be a way to directly format a cell such that Google Sheets recognises it as MM:SS instead of HH:MM, so I've had to go with formulas instead. Sharing the solution I used below.

I set it up so that the user entered the time into cell `A1` in the form MM:SS or H:MM:SS and I formatted this cell as plain text, then had a second cell formatted as 'time duration' where it converted the input of `A1` using the following formula:

```
=time(left(A1,if(len(A1)<6,"",len(A1)-6)),right(left(A1,len(A1)-3),2),right(A1,2))
```

To break this down:

- It starts by assuming the contents of `A1` is a text string with 5 or more characters in the form MM:SS or H:MM:SS or HH:MM:SS. It does not include any sort of error handling to check this is true.
- The `time(X,Y,Z)` part of the formula converts different inputs into hours, minutes and seconds, respectively, and produces a number in the format HH:MM:SS, which is recognised as a time, and can therefore be used in formulas. Note that the cell has to be formatted as 'time duration' to display correctly.
- In the above, `Z` is `right(A1,2)` which extracts the last two characters of `A1`, i.e. the SS part of the input. These end up as seconds.
- Likewise, `Y` is `right(left(A1,len(A1)-3),2)` which extracts the 4th and 5th characters from the right of the text string of `A1`, i.e. the MM part of the input, after the `:`. This number is then recognised as minutes.
- Finally, `X` is `left(A1,if(len(A1)<6,"",len(A1)-6))`, which basically says "if `A1` is less than 6 characters then it must not have hours, so leave blank, otherwise extract out all characters except the last 6", i.e. the HH part of the input, if it exists. This number (which may or may not be 0) is then recognised as hours.